# Allow unknown arguments using argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I have a python script that requires the user to enter two arguments to run it, the arguments could be named anything.

I have also used argparse to allow the users to use a switch '-h' to get instructions of what is required to run the script.

The problem is that now I have used argparse I am getting an error when I pass my two randomly named arguments with the script.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)

parser.add_argument('-h', '--help', action='help',
                    help='To run this script please provide two arguments')
parser.parse_args()
```

currently when I run **python test.py arg1 arg2** the error is

```
error: unrecognized arguments: arg1 arg2
```

I would like the code to allow the user to run test.py with a -h if required to see the instructions but also allow them to run the script with any two arguments as well.

**Resolution** with help tag to provide the user with context regarding the arguments required.

```
   parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)

    parser.add_argument('-h', '--help', action='help', help='To run this script please provide two arguments: first argument should be your scorm package name, second argument should be your html file name. Note: Any current zipped folder in the run directory with the same scorm package name will be overwritten.')
    parser.add_argument('package_name', action="store",  help='Please provide your scorm package name as the first argument')
    parser.add_argument('html_file_name', action="store", help='Please provide your html file name as the second argument')

    parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: Have you read the [argparse tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/argparse.html)? It seems that you didn't declare any arguments, but if you want to know how to use and document them, you'll need a lot more knowledge than can be put in a quick answer.

Comment: Also consider [click](https://palletsprojects.com/p/click/) as an alternative, it's quite popular for being a little easier to use.

Comment: You need to `add_argument` with the right [parameters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-add-argument-method) (`nargs`/`required`/...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='sample')

# Add mandatory arguments
parser.add_argument('arg1', action="store")
parser.add_argument('arg2', action="store")

# Parse the arguments
args = parser.parse_args()
# sample usage of args
print (float(args.arg1) + float(args.arg2))
```

Comment: That worked, I have also added the help switch to add comments about what is required from the argument.

Answer (score 7):

Try the following code :-

```
 import argparse

 parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)

 parser.add_argument('-h', '--help', action='help',
                help='To run this script please provide two arguments')
 parser.add_argument('arg1')
 parser.add_argument('arg2')

 args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()
```

All your unknown arguments will be parsed in `unknown` and all known in `args`.

Comment: I realize this answer probably wasn't what the OP was looking for, but it was what I was looking for in my Google search that landed me here.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add those arguments to the parser:

```
parser.add_argument("--arg1", "-a1", dest='arg1', type=str)
parser.add_argument("--arg2","-a2", dest='arg2', type=str)
```

If those arguments don't have the param *required=true*, you will be able to call the program without this arguments, so you can run the program with only the *-h* flag. To run the program with the arguments:

```
python test.py --arg1 "Argument" --arg2 "Argument"
```

Then, to have the arguments in variables you have to read them:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
argument1=args.arg1
argument2=args.arg2
```

Comment: This is just simply not true. `ArgumentParser` supports parsing out the unknown arguments, as answered in mujjiga's answer above.