# python argparse: allow unregistered arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I am trying to allow unknown arguments using argparse, without typing tons of quote marks as in the `json.loads` solution presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57411734/allow-unknown-arguments-using-argparse).

The `fire` package manages to do this.

For example saving the following program to example.py

```py
import fire

def example_fire_function( **kwargs):
    print(kwargs)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fire.Fire(example_fire_function)
```

and invoking it with

```sh
python example.py --dringus 4
```

Outputs `{'dringus': 4}`, as desired.

Is this possible with just the built in `argparse` package? I already have a large list of argparse arguments and want to add this on top.

Comment: No.  `parse_known_args` will put the unknowns in a list, but splitting them into a key/value pair is your job.  Or just parse `sys.argv` directly.  The point to using `argparse` is to give you, the programmer, control over what the user provides (including usage help).  There's no need for it if any 'flag value' pair is allowed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use argparse to capture an arbitrary set of optional arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37367331/is-it-possible-to-use-argparse-to-capture-an-arbitrary-set-of-optional-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

No. `parse_known_args` will put the unknowns in a list, but splitting them into a key/value pair is your job. Or just parse `sys.argv` directly. The point to using `argparse` is to give you, the programmer, control over what the user provides (including usage help). There's no need for it if any 'flag value' pair is allowed.

*<sub>Copied from [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63329044/python-argparse-allow-unregistered-arguments#comment111983641_63329044)</sub>*